# How to change a "." to a "," in vb 6

Tags: visual-studio, vb6

I'm modifying an old application in vb 6 (for my job) which read data into a database and then I write these data into a csv file.

I have no problem to read data, but when I write them into the csv file, the entire part and the decimal part is separated by a ".". But I need to separate these by a ","

Can you help me to build a little function which do that please ?

Comment: How is it written? It's most likely using a system locale setting.

Comment: If the program is using `Write #` statements then this is expected. Such files are meant as internal files to be used by the program and not to be examined or edited by hand. The point is to use a "universal format" for various data types, allowing files to be interchanged across locales. This is much as in XML, where decimal point is ALWAYS the "." and never a comma.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the built-in function `Replace` to do that:

```
  new_string = replace(old_string, ".", ",")
```

Answer (score 3):

```
mystring = Replace(sourceString, ".", ",")
```

See [here](http://www.tek-tips.com/faqs.cfm?fid=418) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bt3szac5%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) for more information.